# Python 3.7 throws NameError on a type annotation but I dont want to import the module which defines it

Tags: python, python-3.7, nameerror, type-annotation

I have the following structure

in _base.py

```
class Base():
 ...
```

and now in code.py

```
import typing

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _base import Base


    def foo(arg:Base):
       ...
```

Python throws a `NameError` on `Base` but I don't want to import it. I don't have a real reason for it. Especially if `foo()` is not even doing anything with `arg` but sending it further to another module. Type checkers are covered by the load cycle import ( `if TYPE_CHECKING:` ).

Why would python evaluate the type annotation at all? I don't understand why it has to tell what `Base` is. Why doesn't it just store it as a string exactly as I wrote it even if it is complete nonsense? What are the usages of the annotations that warrant it to be valid expressions and not just an arbitrary expressions

Comment: Use a string annotation. They're not just for forward references.

Comment: "I also don't want to explicitly annotate all child classes and import those `Union[Base,A,B]`" - you don't need to. `Base` covers subclasses already.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112supportsMonica - do you know why does Python evaluate those at all? I am a bit reluctant to "hide" them from Python in case it actually will start doing something super cool with the annotations in one of the future versions. So to hide or to expose, this is the question.

Comment: "in case it actually will start doing something super cool with the annotations in one of the future versions" - [it's more likely to do the opposite](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/).

Comment: Without `from _base import Base` it is impossible to tell if `Base` is from `_base` or from `_another_base`. So you have to import it anyway.

Comment: @sanyash - that is the whole point of my frustration. I don't understand why it has to tell what Base is. The linter will know due to the import inside TYPE_CHECKING. But why does the interpreter need to evaluate that type? Why doesn't it just store it as a string exactly as I wrote it even if it is complete nonsense? I mean, the interpreter needs to do nothing with that label. What do I miss? What are the usages of annotations that warrant it to be valid expressions and not just arbitrary expressions